# How to get pagelayout without going through all of them?

Tags: development, page-layout

I know the name of the layout page. Do I still have to go through this process to get the layout page?

```
foreach (PageLayout pl in pageLayouts)
{
if (pl.Name.Equals("MyLayout.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    currPageLayout = pl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess if I know the content type id then it can be. http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=70640fe5%2D28d9%2D464f%2Db1c9%2D91e07c8f7e47&ID=35

PageLayout[] layouts =            publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts(contentType.Id);

Comment: what is your variable `pageLayouts`?

Answer (score 2):

Since a PageLayout is just an SPFile in an SPList (Master Page Gallery), you can get a reference to the SPFile and use the PageLayout constructor to get your PageLayout by passing in SPFile.Item

Something like this

```
new PageLayout(site.RootWeb.Files["webrelativeurltoyourpagelayout.aspx"].Item);
```

Comment: that did not work. hmm. any other suggesion(s)?

Comment: Did you manage to get a valid reference to the SPFile? What value did you use for webrelativeurltoyourpagelayout.aspx?

Comment: this worked for me: new PageLayout(site.RootWeb.GetFile("_catalogs/masterpage/newLayout.aspx").Item);